# How can i copy from textBox1 the text to textBox2 including spaces?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a text the user enter manual in textBox1
Then a button click that copy the text from textBox1 to textBox2 but in textBox2 the text looks like long one string .

I want that when it copy the text it will also copy the exact spaces between the words.

In my new class i have this code in the top :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ScrambleRandomWordsTest
{
    class ScrambleTextBoxText
    {
        private static readonly Random RandomGen = new Random();
        private List<string> _words;
        private List<string> _scrambledWords;

        public ScrambleTextBoxText(List<string> textBoxList)
        {
            _words = textBoxList;
        }
```

Then in the bottom i have this function :

```
public List<string> scrambledTextBoxWords()
        {
            List<string> words = _scrambledWords;
            return words;
        }
```

Then in Form1 in the button click event i have :

```
private void BtnScrambleText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Enabled = false;
            BtnScrambleText.Enabled = false;
            textBoxWords = ExtractWords(textBox1.Text);
            ScrambleTextBoxText scrmbltb = new ScrambleTextBoxText(textBoxWords);
            for (int i = 0; i < scrmbltb.scrambledTextBoxWords().Count; i++)
            {
                textBox2.AppendText(scrmbltb.scrambledTextBoxWords()[i]);
            }
        }
```

So i type some text in Form1 for example :

danny hello       yellow

Then i make instance for the new class and get back a List of the words as i wanted.
And add them to textBox2 with AppendText

Thep roblem is that in textBox2 the text will look like :

dannyhelloyellow

And i want it to look the same as it was in textBox1 including the spaces:
For example between hello and yellow there are 7 spaces so in textBox2 it will look like:

danny hello       yellow

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the easiest way is

```
textBox2.Text = String.Join(" ", scrmbtb.scrambledTextBoxWords());
```

Using your current solution

```
textBox2.AppendText(scrmbltb.scrambledTextBoxWords()[i] + " ");
```

If that is all your function is doing you'd be better to change your class to something similar.

You have

```
private List<string> _scrambledWords;
public List<string> scrambledTextBoxWords()
{
    List<string> words = _scrambledWords;
    return words;
}
```

which is the same as

```
public List<string> ScrambledTextBoxWords {get; private set;}
```

then

```
textBox2.Text = String.Join(" ", scrmbtb.ScrambledTextBoxWords);
```